# Space between TextFormFields

Tags: user-interface, dart, uitextfield, flutter

I am working on a Flutter app.
I have this dart code:

```
List<Widget> buildInputs() {
    return[
      new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 20.0,
          right: 40.0,
          left: 40.0,
        ),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail', contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.0)),
              validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'nt be empty' : null,
              onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
              ),
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password', contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.0)),
              obscureText: true,
              validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'nt be empty' : null,
              onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }
```

As you can see I use this: `contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.0)`
I use this that the title of the `TextFormField` is closer too the TextFormFieldLine.
Now, how to add a top space between the two `TextFormField`s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There Are Few Ways to get it Done :

**1st  Padding Widget:** Wrap With Form Field with Padding Widget

```
Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                child: new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'E-Mail',
                      contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.0)),
                  validator: (value) =>
                      value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'nt be empty' : null,
                  // onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                child: new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.0)),
                  obscureText: true,
                  validator: (value) =>
                      value.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'nt be empty' : null,
                  // onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

**2nd SizedBox Widget:** I prefer this method to add space between Form Fields as its clean & less Code.

```
Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'E-Mail',
                    contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.0)),
                validator: (value) =>
                    value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'nt be empty' : null,
                // onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 25.0,),
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.0)),
                obscureText: true,
                validator: (value) =>
                    value.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'nt be empty' : null,
                // onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just add a `SizedBox` (a very basic widget without decoration) between the text fields:

```
SizedBox(height: 8.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `Wrap(runSpacing:8, children:[])`